# Save form data in two models in Odoo

Tags: forms, insert, odoo, formbuilder

I have created two models (`A` and `B`) with the same fields, only for backup purposes. I created a form with `A` as model using HTML Form Builder. Normally, form data will save in table A (model `A`). I want to save the data that is inserted in the `B` model as well.

Comment: You should definitely add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If this models are identical just override the create and write and unlink method in A model to execute the same operation in B.
But for unlink  and write I think you need to keep the `id` of model `B` in model A so when you delete a record from A you delete the corresponding record in b. nothing will confirm that the ids will be the sames.

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
   a_id = super(YourClassName, self).create(vals)
   b_id = self.env['B'].create(vals) # here no one will confirm that both have the same id
   a_id.many2one_b_id = b_id  # so you can execute write and unlink
   return rec_id

@api.muli
def write(self,vals):
    # don't forget using api.multi self can contain more than one record
    # using mapped is better than looping through records and execute write
    # one by one. and using api.one have the same effect
    super(YourClassName, self).write(vals)
    # using mapped will execute only one update queries for all ids
    self.mapped('many2one_b_id').write(vals)  # mapped will return the list of B record

    return True

@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    # same thing for delete
    # delete B record first
    self.mapped('many2one_b_id').unlink()
    super(YourClassName, self).unlinck()
```